# How do I set "JsonReaderQuotas" property on the DotNetOpenAuth "OAuth2ClientChannel" class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth, instagram

I am using DotNetOpenAuth to authenticate with Instagram. Unfortunately, I get the following error back

> The maximum read depth (2) has been exceeded because XML data being read has more levels of nesting than is allowed by the quota. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxDepth property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.

From a bit of looking around I saw that a fix was added to version 4.2 of DotNetOpenAuth that allows you to override the default maximum levels, a property called `JsonReaderQuotas` on the `OAuth2ClientChannel`. I can't however, seem to see how to set or override this property to fix the issue.

Does anyone know how to override the default value or know of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClientBase someClient; // initialized elsewhere
someClient.JsonReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 10;
```